# Release application with someone's package name

Tags: android

My question may look strange but I'll try to explain somehow. Let's imagine there is an Android device with software that adjusts some settings based on application package name - it's a real-life scenario. This software may provide better performance for listed applications and there is no way to add my application to that list. What I'm capable of doing is to release my application under one of listed package names (not to Google Play, just provide APK on GitHub so that anyone who wants to use it will install it manually). And there comes my question:
is it legal to use some company's existing package name for my own application? Is it protected legally? My app is free & open source application.

Just to be clear: I'm not doing this to impersonate "real" application with bad intentions. I just want my application to use full range of device capabilities... And download page will state it clearly & visibly :)

In other words: can I release app with package name e.g. com.google.android.talk? I know that it won't override existing app if someone has it installed etc. (it's not my goal to override some application). I'm just talking about such possibility and legality.

Comment: Any software that uses the "package name" as a trusted value without actually checking the package signature to verify that the package was signed by the expected signatory is very lame.

Comment: It's related to some capabilities: e.g. if some application is on that list extra buttons appear... and there are applications that vendor wanted :/ Any other, which probably don't provide income for the vendor, cannot use all device possibilities... And I just wanted to allow people used them...

Answer (score 0):

This is totally legal, as you can use whatever String you want for your app/package name.

However, just doing this will most probably be not enough to "impersonate" the other app, as this would be a serious security flaw. First of all, there can never be two apps with the same package name installed.

If the app you speak about is created by a "serious" developer, say Google or one of the OEMs, it will **check both package and signature of the app** and will therefore know your app is not the same as the replaced app.

Also, when the user tries to install your app, a package conflict will happen, followed by the signature conflict. There are two scenarios here:

1. If the app you are replacing is a standard app, the user will be able to install your app from adb, but only after thay accept to completely wipe the data of the original app. You have probably seen this dialog while developing stuff.
2. If the app is provided by the OEM and has system permissions, the installation will simply fail, with no possibility to "overwrite" the app. This can be dodged by having the devices rooted, replacing the .apk file in the system directory and restarting the phone.

**Please mind that none of the above will work by just uploading the .apk to the phone. This needs to be done from adb. On-phone installer will just fail.**

Comment: I tested it and it works :) I signed application with my own keystore and installed using ES file explorer.
Many thanks for your response. I chose package name from that list of application I could not find anywhere - it could be a possible workaround created by a vendor so that once new app is released by them they wouldn't have to release software update.